Trying to build a custom Retry tag for Reqnroll Gherkin syntax
I am tyrying to build a custom Retry Hook for use with Reqnroll (the newer Specflow), and I am having some difficulty re-running the test. I am curios how I can actually re-run the same test on failure up to n times. Here is what I have for now:
namespace Hooks.SharedHooks
{

    [Binding]
    public class RetryHook
    {
        private int _retryCount;
        private const int DefaultMaxRetries = 2;
        private static readonly Regex RetryTag = new Regex(@"^Retry");
        private static readonly Regex RetryTagNumbereRegex = new Regex(@"^Retry\(\d+)\)$");

        [BeforeScenario("Retry","Retry*")]
        public void BeforeScenario()
        {
            _retryCount = 0;
        }

        [AfterScenario("Retry", "Retry*", Order = 0)]
        public void AfterScenario(ScenarioContext scenarioContext, ITestRunnerManager testRunnerManager)
        {
            var maxRetries = GetMaxRetriesFromScenario(scenarioContext) ?? DefaultMaxRetries;
            while (_retryCount < maxRetries && scenarioContext.TestError != null)
            {
                _retryCount++;
                Console.WriteLine($"Attempting scenario '{scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title}' try {_retryCount} of {maxRetries}");
                ScenarioExecutionRetryAsync(scenarioContext, testRunnerManager);
            } 
        }

        private int? GetMaxRetriesFromScenario(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
        {
            foreach (var tag in scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Tags)
            {
                var match = RetryTagNumbereRegex.Match(tag);
                if (match.Success && int.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value, out int retries))
                {
                    return retries;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        private void ScenarioExecutionRetry(ScenarioContext scenarioContext,ITestRunnerManager manager)
        {
            // Logic to re-run the failed scenario

        }
    }

Any idea how I can write the ScenarioExecutionRetry method?

I think this is something the test runner itself implements. SpecFlow isn't a test runner, it is a test framework.

so in my case it would be NUnit?

NUnit is a test framework and a test runner. How are you running the tests?

locally, through the test explorer on  VS; from the feature files. In the pipeline through the cmd, NUnit

As pointed in the comments, This is something that the test runner does.
The long answer ivolves working through with NUnit and creating custom plugins for it. The simple answer is use another [Retry] package such as the Databindings.Reqnroll.NUnit.Retry
